# Use nodeJS server with symfony

Tags: node.js, symfony

I have a huge symfony app and I wanted to add some feature that I could only do with a nodeJS server .

So I have a big JSON file which result from my nodeJS run, this file have to go in Symfony.
And symfony have to be able to send some pdf file to the node server (the one which will be transform in JSON by my node server).

Is anyone have some starting idea ?

thansk for help :D

Answer (score 0):

No one is going to be able to provide a full answer with so few details, but generally speaking messaging and remote procedure calls are excellent for interop between parts of a large app.

You could send a message from Symfony (which includes the path of the PDF, or the contents itself), and node will provide the result. You can encode that as JSON, and send it as an answer.

RabbitMq is widely supported, allows both produce-consume or RPC-style use.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, sorry for the the question not detail at all. I haven't so more information yet. I will look for what you say . :D Thanks

Comment: Ok now I understand a little bit better what is RPC and difference with websocket. 
I'm affraid of RabbitMq, it's seems heavy and hard to deploy for newbie.
I found an other RPC : DNode-php which seems to be like RabbitMq, [DNode-php](https://github.com/bergie/dnode-php) .
What do you think of it ? 
Many thanks by advance for your help 
Axel

Comment: I understand your reluctance to use rabbitmq, but I would not recommend using this lib at all. It is archieved, last commit from 2014. Rabbit is not that hard to learn, and essential knowledge, so sooner or later you will have to...

Comment: If you really don't want to learn it now, maybe you could just call your node script with a symfony process, and output json. It's not nice, but it will do the job.

Comment: Ok I will try to learn it anyway ;-), do you have some example of "call the node script with a symfony process" ? The nodejs server will run if we do like that?
Sorry for these questions, it's a mess in my head.
Thanks by advance,
Axel